# Installing libfile-homedir-perl in docker based on Raspbian Jessie

Tags: docker, perl, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I'm trying to install the package libfile-homedir-perl in a docker container, based on Raspbian Jessie (balenalib/rpi-raspbian). I based my Dockerfiles on: https://github.com/michaelmiklis/docker-rpi-loxberry/blob/master/Dockerfile. The build of the Dockerfile hangs on "Setting up libfile-homedir-perl" without any more info. I left it open overnight, without any change.

I try to install with this line:

```
 apt-get install -y libfile-homedir-perl
```

This is the output, nothing happens after the last line.

```
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libfile-which-perl
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libfile-homedir-perl libfile-which-perl
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 10 not upgraded.
Need to get 62.0 kB of archives.
After this operation, 155 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian/ jessie/main libfile-which-perl all 1.09-1 [13.1 kB]
Get:2 http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian/ jessie/main libfile-homedir-perl all 1.00-1 [48.9 kB]
Fetched 62.0 kB in 0s (425 kB/s)
Selecting previously unselected package libfile-which-perl.
(Reading database ... 11488 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libfile-which-perl_1.09-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking libfile-which-perl (1.09-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libfile-homedir-perl.
Preparing to unpack .../libfile-homedir-perl_1.00-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking libfile-homedir-perl (1.00-1) ...
Setting up libfile-which-perl (1.09-1) ...
Setting up libfile-homedir-perl (1.00-1) ...
```

Is there any log file I can check for other information?
How would I go about getting this problem solved?

Comment: What base image is this Dockerfile built on? Ubuntu?

Comment: What happens if you remove `libfile-homedir-perl` from the `Dockerfile` ? Does it build successfully then ?